# How to transpose specific csv table?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am new to programming, i have a data look like this:

```
name | age | address | phone |
------------------------------
hei  | 18  | home    | 123   |
     |     |         | 231   |
     |     |         | 432   |
------------------------------
hay  | 19  | house   | 455   |
     |     |         | 555   |
     |     |         | 666   |
------------------------------
```

is there any way to make it like this:

```
name | age | address | phone | phone | phone |
----------------------------------------------
hei  | 18  | home    | 123   | 231   | 432   |
----------------------------------------------
hay  | 19  | house   | 455   | 555   | 666   |
```

i read the file with this code:

```
import pandas as pd
pf = pd.read_csv('test.csv)
```

Comment: Is this in a `pandas` dataframe? Can you show the actual text in the csv file and the code you used to read it? I can't tell whether name, age and address are repeated across rows but omitted from your display, or whether they're actually missing in the data.

Comment: @MatthiasFripp it is actually look like that

Comment: If the data file has the '|'s and '-'s in it, I suspect using Search/Replace in a text editor would be the fastest way to solve the problem.

Comment: Does your first box show what happens when you display `pf` in Python? Or is it the actual contents of test.csv? Can you put the contents of test.csv in that text box instead?

Comment: Is this a grouped object? Or is phone a string column?

Answer (score 0):

df1 =

```
name | age | address | phone |
------------------------------
hei  | 18  | home    | 123   |
     |     |         | 231   |
     |     |         | 432   |
------------------------------
hay  | 19  | house   | 455   |
     |     |         | 555   |
     |     |         | 666   |
------------------------------
```

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d1)
df2.drop(columns=['phone'])
```

Please change the below to however you want to.

```
df2[['phone','phone1','phone2']] = pd.DataFrame(df1.phone.values.tolist(), index= df2.index)
```

```
name | age | address | phone | phone1 | phone2|
----------------------------------------------
hei  | 18  | home    | 123   | 231    | 432   |
----------------------------------------------
hay  | 19  | house   | 455   | 555    | 666   |
-----------------------------------------------
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Given this df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['a',"","",'b',"",""], 'age':[18,"","",19,"",""], 'address':['home',"","",'house',"",""],'phone':[123,456,546,432,423,654]})
print (df)

  name age address  phone
0    a  18    home    123
1                     456
2                     546
3    b  19   house    432
4                     423
5                     654
```

You can do in this way:

```
df = df.replace('', np.nan)
df1 = df.copy()
df1.dropna(subset=['name'], inplace = True)
df1 = df1.drop('phone', 1)   
df = df.ffill()
s = df.groupby('name').phone.apply(list)
df = pd.DataFrame(s.values.tolist(), s.index).add_prefix('phone').fillna('').reset_index()
final_df = (pd.merge(df, df1, on='name'))
print (final_df)
```

Output:

```
  name  phone0  phone1  phone2   age address
0    a     123     456     546  18.0    home
1    b     432     423     654  19.0   house
```